# Puppeteer: Getting the correct frame element in page request

Tags: puppeteer

I've got a scenario where I'm trying to map the network requests to the element who triggered the request.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on("request", async request => {
  request.continue();
  const frame = request.frame();
  const frameContent = await frame.content();
  console.log("URL:", url, "\n\nFRAME:\n", frameContent);
})

await page.goto('https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html')
```

**Output**

```
URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsjavascriptsdk/latest/css/style.css  

FRAME content:  
<html><head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
  Class: AWS.S3

    — AWS SDK for JavaScript

</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/highlight.github.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  pathId = "AWS.S3";
  relpath = '../';
</script></head></html>
```

Here the `frame.content()` is giving a larger block of the originator.
Is there anyway I can just get the element from where the request originated?
In this case :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: There is no way to track that.

Comment: @hardkoded: Just as I feared, do you think there is an alternate approach, I'm sure it won't be perfect.

Comment: I could try to take a look at the `tracing` output. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @hardkoded: Tried tracing but unfortunately didn't have the info I'm looking for.
Probably need to find the component responsible for parsing the links and converting them to network url.

Comment: well, there is a way but it's not easy. we did a project like that a while ago, but you need to instrument the browser for that. I'm not affiliated with this project but take a look at what Brave is doing: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki/PageGraph